# CAGR and mutate function problems

Tags: r, dplyr

I have very little experience in R, and am currently trying to create a function which calculates the CAGR (compounded annual growth rate) of my financial data (the gross profit at time t=0 and t=-2).

I have imported the gross profits from an excel file (called Forsog_orbis_til_rv2) and want to create a new variable called CAGR in this data frame. I have used the following code:.

```
library(tibble);
library(dplyr)

grossprofit.t <- c(818000,883000,4141000,123000,5301000,4788000)
grossprofit.t2 <- c(2375000,2279000,-69000,5604000,3959000,6240000)
mydata <- data.frame(grossprofit.t,grossprofit.t2)

CAGR_formula <- function(FV, PV, yrs = 2) {
  values <- ((FV/PV)^(1/yrs)-1)
  return(values)
}

mydata %>%
  mutate(CAGR=CAGR_formula(grossprofit.t,grossprofit.t2,2)*100)`

print(mydata)
```

When I do this, the output only includes my two gross profit-variables.. What am I doing wrong with the mutate function or the CAGR function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to assign your pipe sequence to a variable.

```
mydata <- mydata %>%
  mutate(CAGR=CAGR_formula(grossprofit.t2,grossprofit.t,2)*100)

print(mydata)
```